# What is the median concentration of spike antigen in COVID positive patients?

Tags: proteins, coronavirus, literature

I am searching for the plasma spike concentration in COVID patients. [The closest possible reference I found](https://academic.oup.com/clinchem/article/66/12/1562/5902449?login=true) claims that spike was only detectable in 5 of 64 COVID-19 positive patients.

However, their spike assay is relatively insensitive with a LOD (limit of detection) of 70 pg spike protein/ml; multiple vaccine-related studies detected a spike concentration of around 1 pg/ml.

Are there better sources?